# How to get Tailwind's CSS to be applied after deploying on Netlify

Tags: html, tailwind-css, netlify

I'm using Tailwind CSS and after I deploy to Netlify, it seems only the HTML is displayed. The CSS classes are not being applied.

I tried moving my `output.css` file to the `src` folder that contains the HTML and it still didn't work.

Comment: It would be helpful if you'd add your `package.json`, `postcss.config.js`, and `tailwind.config.js` files to your question (assuming you're using React).

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: Here is the tailwind.config.js  /** @type {import('tailwindcss').Config} */
module.exports = {
  content: ["./src/**/*.{html,js}"],
  theme: {
    screens: { sm: "480px", md: "768px", lg: "976px", xl: "1440px" },
    extend: {
      colors: {
        strongCyan: "hsl(171,66%,44%)",
        lightBlue: "hsl(233,100%,69%)",
        darkGrayishBlue: "hsl(210,10%,33%)",
        grayishBlue: "hsl(201,11%,66%)",
      },
      fontFamily: { sans: ["Bai Jamjuree", "sans-serif"] },
    },
  },
  plugins: [],
};

Comment: At first, after deploy it shows 'page not found'. Then I figured it was as a result of the folder where the index.html was. Now, all the shows after deploy is just the HTML of the project.